# CStringList documentation

Tags: c++

At the beginning of the page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstringlist-class?view=msvc-170

one can see the following line:

```
CObject*& CObList::GetHead() const;
```

Can you explain me what it is?

1. It looks like a function declaration.
   Yet in a class `.h` file, we wouldn't prefix the function name with the class name `CObList::`
2. Also, is `CObject*&` a function return type?

I am familiar with parameters passed as references using a `&` like for example:

```
void CMyClass::FindCountry(CString & szCountry)
{
    [...]
}
```

3. What does the `const` keyword mean in that context?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is a declaration of a `CObList` member function. It's not a proper C++ declaration (since it's done outside the class without a definition), but a declaration nevertheless.
2. Yes, the function returns a reference to a `CObject` pointer.
3. `const` means that the function promises to not change the `CObList` object. It's `const` qualified.

Comment: Thank you. Can you be so very kind to explain to me what it is useful for for a function to return a reference to a CObject pointer? Maybe you can give me an example?

Comment: Can you tell me what the < and > characters means in "POSITION AddHead( CObject* <newElement> );" in the same documentation? Thanks.

Comment: @LéaMassiot You're welcome. Returning a pointer by reference makes it possible to bind to the original pointer. Calling `auto& obj = x.GetHead();` and then changing what `obj` points at will change the pointer returned by `GetHead()`. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/j6MvsMn9G)

Comment: `<newElement>` is just a documentation detail and is also not proper C++. They could have made it `newElement` instead to not confuse readers.

Comment: Thank you and especially for the example. In the `CObList::GetHead()` documentation, I can read: "If the list is accessed directly or through a pointer to a CObList, then GetHead returns a reference to a CObject pointer. This allows the function to be used on either side of an assignment statement and thus allows the list entries to be modified." Does it mean `GetHead()` can change the head of the list after all? If I relate to your example, a similar code would change the head, the first pointer in the list, wouldn't it?

Comment: @LéaMassiot Yes, that's correct. I don't know how `CObList` is implemented but if it's like a view over some externally allocated resource the `const` qualification will still honor the promise (since the actual `CObject*` it returns a reference to is owned "elsewhere") - or if it owns the resource, but the resource it is `mutable`, the `const` qualification would still not pose a problem.

Comment: Thank you. It is not easy to understand all the implications of such a declaration. In your example, ptr is not a member of the struct, it is "elsewhere".

Comment: @LéaMassiot Yes. In a real implementation I would assume some dynamic memory allocation and management instead of a single raw pointer though :-)